# High Performance Highly Available Tracking System

Tags: amazon-ec2, tracking, high-availability

I currently hold a tracking service that records visits from various sources. At times we record the visits and redirect to our clients or we let clients call us to report visits. The architecture is two worker boxes configured behind a load-balancer. This system is setup using Amazon EC2 and the load-balancer used is Amazon's Elastic LB.

I did some benchmarking tests and have noticed significant network latencies. The traffic through load-balancer suffers atleast 2 times more delay than hitting any of the boxes directly.

- Has anyone experienced such an issue and has attempted to solve it? Is this an Amazon EC2 specific issue?
- Is there any other architecture in use that would lower my network latencies significantly. e.g. Using a HA such that traffic needn't go through a load-balancer but instead hits the end point servers directly? Before I start investing time on that I wanted to hear what others think of the same.

Thanks alot for your time,
Santosh

Answer (score 1):

Change your LB and give it another try. HAProxy is great session/cookie aware L7 balancer and can be setup in Amazon cloud AFAIK. See this: http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2009/02/load-balancing-in-amazon-ec2-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into account that ELBs perform better after a while, then initially. Don't ask me why, but that's how it is -- loadbalancer warming?

It also really depends how much traffic you sent the ELB. Keep in mind that the hardware the ELB is provisioned on seems like a regular small instance. So the throughput is capped at ~25 MBit (last time I checked). If you require more, go dedicated.

In the end, I too would suggest that you look Haproxy on a dedicated instance. I'd expect some delay, 2x more delay sounds unreal. Maybe use another small instance and benchmark it directly against the ELB and then try a `c1.medium`.